# server response was: smtp23.relay.iad3b.emailsrvr.com

Tags: .net

Error getting when we send email from server, but in local system email perfectly working.

**Exception :**
*The server response was: smtp23.relay.iad3b.emailsrvr.com esmtp not accepting connections*

```
        MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage();
        MyMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("noreply@xxxx.com");
        MyMailMessage.To.Add(To);
        MyMailMessage.Subject = Subject;
        MyMailMessage.Body = Template1;
        MyMailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure |
                    DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess |
                    DeliveryNotificationOptions.Delay;
        MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.emailsrvr.com");
        SMTPServer.Port = 8025;
        SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreply@xxx.com","xxx");
        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = false;
        SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated on link below, maybe the error is that the senders IP address is suspected of sending spam and is blacklisted.
[https://support.mailhostbox.com/email-administrators-guide-error-codes/#:~:text=When%20sending%20an%20email%20to,sending%20spam%20and%20is%20blacklisted.&text=A%20problem%20has%20occurred%20during,to%20this%20e%2Dmail%20address](https://support.mailhostbox.com/email-administrators-guide-error-codes/#:%7E:text=When%20sending%20an%20email%20to,sending%20spam%20and%20is%20blacklisted.&text=A%20problem%20has%20occurred%20during,to%20this%20e%2Dmail%20address).

Comment: how to fix this issue? do u have any idea